# How can I call a function if that function will not be called by another function?

Tags: javascript

I've run into a problem I don't know how to solve properly.

To simplify the problem, I've created a minimum example that demonstrates this problem without XY problem issues.

Basically I have 3 functions: `foo`, `bar` and `start`.

And my program has two ways to start:

- Case 1: Calling `foo()` then calling `bar()`
- Case 2: Only calling `foo()`

Those two ways are triggered by user input that I simulated with button clicks.

My goal is no matter which case, `start` will always gets called exactly once.

`bar()` has a chance to call `start()` after a short amount of time. If `bar` will cause `start` to be called, then I don't need to call `start` from `foo()`, `start` call from `foo()` should be a fallback that doesn't overwrite the actual call from `bar`. It's okay to call `start()` after a reasonable delay, also it would be preferred if I only need to modify the function `foo` to achieve it.

I cannot modify functions `case1()` and `case2()` since these are simulated function calls.

- Expected outcomes

| case | condition | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| case 1 | `bar` will trigger `start` | `foo`, `bar`, `start bar` |
| case 1 | `bar` will not trigger `start` | `foo`, `bar`, `start foo` |
| case 2 | `bar` doesn't get called | `foo`, `start foo` |

Sorry if it sounds complicated but I tried to make it as simple as possible.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
  
  // if start will not be called, call start manually
  // start('foo');
}

function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
  
  // The API call may take some time
  wait(3000 * Math.random()).then(() => {
  
    // has a chance to call start
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
      start('bar');
    }
  });
}

function start(origin) {
  console.log('start', origin);
}


// ------ simulated cases -------

function case1() {
  foo();
  bar();
}

function case2() {
  foo();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="case1()">Case 1</button>
<button onclick="case2()">Case 2</button>
```

Comment: Use a global variable that says whether `start` was called. Check that variable before calling `start()`.

Comment: Or `start()` could check the variable, and return if it has already been called.

Comment: The issue is on case 2, `start()` will not be called at all. And If I call `start` in `foo` by default, the actual `start()` call from `bar()` function will be overwritten which is not what I want.

Comment: you can convert your bar function to an async function. Because you run start() there with 50% random chance and it is not really connected to anything else. So you can await for api call to end then run start(). If this is not really what you are looking for, maybe you can have a setInterval function and a global variable. setInterval checks for the variable value. depending on the value, either you run start or clearInterval